Discord.js Как добавить дискорд-бота в несколько голосовых каналов одновременно?
Всем привет!
Есть ли возможность добавить одного и того же бота в несколько голосовых каналов сервера?
Я хочу, чтобы в каждом голосовом канале было по экземпляру бота, но не хотелось бы приглашать на сервер 10 разных ботов

По идее бота — точно такой же аккаунт, как и у обычного пользователя, просто с пометкой бот, которая дает некоторые ограничения. Поэтому в двух каналах одновременно бот находиться не может. Это догадка. Ну и есть такой же вопрос на английской версии сайта: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66362140/14519908
